# How can I debug PayPalCoreSDK IPN validation failures?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using PayPal's own .NET library to validate IPNs, specifically [IPNMessage.cs](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/blob/master/Source/SDK/IPNMessage.cs) in [PayPalCoreSDK 1.5.0](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet) available via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPalCoreSDK/) (released 2014-09-09).

Here's how I'm using it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Ipn()
{
    try
    {
        byte[] bytes = Request.BinaryRead(Request.ContentLength);
        IPNMessage message = new IPNMessage(bytes);

        string description = string.Format("PayPal IPN {0} {1} {2}",
            message.IpnValue("txn_id"),
            message.IpnValue("payment_type"),
            message.IpnValue("payment_status"));

        Trace.TraceInformation(description + " Received");

        if (message.Validate())
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation(description + " Valid");
            // do work here
        }
        else
        {
            Trace.TraceError(description + " Invalid");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Trace.TraceError("PayPal IPN Exception: " + e.Message);
    }

    return null;
}
```

And my logs are telling me (txnId changed):

```
Application: 2014-09-11T19:52:40  PID[11584] Information PayPal IPN ABC536DEFP96XYZ3U instant Completed Received
Application: 2014-09-11T19:52:40  PID[11584] Error       PayPal IPN ABC536DEFP96XYZ3U instant Completed Invalid
```

The IPN itself is full of all the keys/values I'm expecting.  When I log into PayPal and look at the Instant Payment Notification (IPN) history section, I see the IPN with a matching transaction ID and its status is "Sent".  I'm just getting back `false` from `Validate()`, so PayPal must not be replying with "VERIFIED".  No exception is thrown, how do I debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my app wasn't even communicating with PayPal.

PayPalCoreSDK requires the following in app.config/web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.Manager.SDKConfigHandler, PayPalCoreSDK" />
  </configSections>
  <paypal>
    <settings>
      <add name="mode" value="sandbox" /> <!-- "live" or "sandbox" -->
    </settings>
  </paypal>
</configuration>
```

Credit to [James Dibble](http://www.jdibble.co.uk/blog/2014/2/4/getting-started-with-the-paypal-rest-api-sdk-for-.net)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on your own answer - yes they are complete idiots in the API.

The IPN message actually contains a flag whether or not the message is sandbox - so it should be able to figure this out for itself without needing explicit config set. Or at the very least it should give an error.

Alternatively you can provide the config like this (I have a `config` object which is just a simple struct)

```
var message = new PayPal.IPNMessage(new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "account1.apiUsername", config.APIUsername },
                { "account1.apiPassword", config.APIPassword },
                { "account1.apiSignature", config.APISignature },

                { "mode", config.IsLiveMode ? "live" : "sandbox" }
            }, bytes);
```

(I'm pretty sure the account user info is not actually required here)

**Wondering why don't you get an error?...**

I actually went into the [source code for IPNMessage](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/blob/v1.6.0/Source/SDK/IPNMessage.cs#L140) to see what was going on. The following call retrieves the URL inside the `validate()` method. It looks in your configuration to find it and throws an exception if it fails (which is what we want).

Unfortunately it is wrapped inside a `try` block which really should only be catching runtime errors - but instead it masks the configuration error and just returns a useless `false` for `validate()`.

```
string ipnEndpoint = GetIPNEndpoint();
```

Comment: if someone can take the time to report this to the github project would be great. All they need to do is move this `GetIPNEndpoint` call up two lines outside of the `try` block

Comment: @simon-weaver, thanks for pinpointing the needed change (and the friendly jab ;) ).  I've gone ahead and opened a [new issue in the SDK on GitHub that links back to this question](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/issues/42).

Comment: OMG I just remembered I actually had a dream about this last night that somebody was arguing against this change! What a nightmare!